# How to handle exceptions that are not thrown by controllers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Consider this piece of code.

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            InitLogger();

            InitAppContext();

            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            // WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();            
        }
```

Let's say an exception occurs in InitLogger.

I see two solutions to handle this:

1. Use Application_Error event to make a request redirect to some page. If i try this approach i get `Request is not available in this context`
2. Use `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.html" />`. If i try his i get `http://localhost:1937/Error.html?aspxerrorpath=/`

How to handle the situation described?

Thanks.

PS: To handle controller exceptions( http exceptions and custom exceptions ) i used a filter, that part is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your solutions talk about redirecting the request to somewhere else. However, your exception is occurring at application startup, and as such there hasn't *been* a request yet.

If InitLogger() can throw an exception, wrap the call in a try/catch block. If you can handle the exception in some way (for example, perhaps you have a second logger that you can try instead, or your application can run without a logger), then go ahead and handle it. If you can't, well - your application isn't going to work, and since you can't fix it on-the-fly you need to record what went wrong somewhere (to help you investigate later). For example, you could write the error to the Event Log, although note that this will happen automatically anyway if you don't catch the exception.